# Using GNU Privacy Guard in .NET

Tags: .net, gnu, gnupg

Is there some way to use GNU Privacy Guard functionality directly? Yes, I know about redirecting input/output streams from gpg.exe utility, but maybe we can use some unmanaged libraries from distribution directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can answer my own question. I was pointed to [Starksoft .NET GnuPG Component](http://web.archive.org/web/20111219021439/http://www.starksoft.com/prod_openpgp.html) - a free library that takes interaction with GPG on itself. Looks like it works fine, even if the project seems to be not maintained for a while.

UPD: The component seems to be available now as a NuGet package at https://www.nuget.org/packages/starksoft.aspen

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested in this.

You prb know about [this wrapper class](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/pgp/article.php/c4699) that wraps the redirecting streams to gpg.exe, but there doesn't seem to be much in the way of libraries.

There is [SharpPrivacy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/sharpprivacy.aspx) but that has been dead a while, I looked at the source code (from codeproject) and the presentation logic is mixed in with the actual code - it needs a lot of tlc. The sourceforge page for it seems to be dead too.

Theres also [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) which may do the job, I've not looked into it yet though, I would suggest it over SharpPrivacy though - let me know how you get on if you pursue this ;)

Comment: How is about GPGME library? Didn't you try to use it?

Comment: Nope, didn't look at that. Don't really fancy trying to get it compiled and working in windows and then calling through unmanaged code.

Answer (score 1):

There are also the BouncyCastle Privacy Guard (BCPG) components of the BouncyCastle csharp library, available at http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/ , if you're looking for native csharp interaction with GPG-encrypted streams.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the projects to CodePlex.  This library is now part of the Biko library and is available in a Alpha release.  http://biko.codeplex.com/